# Prevent MySQL from automatically creating indexes for foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `usersMeta` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `metaKey` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `metaValue` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id` DESC),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId_metaKey` (`userId` DESC,`metaKey`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usersMeta_userId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The key `userId_metaKey` can be used for the foreign key. If I use mysqldump to export the table structure, then import it using `mysql -u user -p db < exports.sql`, MySQL automatically adds new indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `usersMeta` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `metaKey` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `metaValue` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id` DESC),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId_metaKey` (`userId` DESC,`metaKey`),
  KEY `fk_usersMeta_userId` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usersMeta_userId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

It added `fk_usersMeta_userId`, which is unnecessary. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please show us the query that needs `DESC`.  You may be able to get rid if it without harm.  What version of MySQL are you using?  Also, is there any good reason for having `id` at all?  It seems that the `UNIQUE` key could be promoted to be the PK.  (And this would probably speed up your app.)

Comment: Would any of that address the issue of an extra index appearing? E.g. DESC causing MySQL to not recognize the index?

Comment: It's version 8.

Comment: Yes, I am suspecting that `DESC` scared away the "if it does not exist" clause quoted by Bill.  It should be easy to experiment with and without the DESC.  And then file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Makes sense, changing it to `FOREIGN KEY (`userId` DESC)` fixed it, even though I don't think that does anything

Comment: Interesting.  A secret syntax option.  But it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, a foreign key must have an index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html says:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.

---

I experimentally tried to define a table like yours with a slightly different UNIQUE KEY, without the descending option:

```
CREATE TABLE `usersMeta` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `metaKey` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `metaValue` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id` DESC),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId_metaKey` (`userId`,`metaKey`),
                               ^^^^^^^^ not DESC
  CONSTRAINT `usersmeta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

In this design, the foreign key can use the leftmost column of the UNIQUE KEY.

I would suppose that the issue is that the index must have the same direction (ASC vs. DESC) as the key in table it references.

Comment: Yeah it has an index already: `userId_metaKey`. It's able to use the first column for the foreign key